# SQLITE_BUSY The database file is locked (database is locked) in wicket

Tags: sqlite, database-locking

I am doing a project in wicket
How to solve the problem.
I came across such a message:
WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor public itucs.blg361.g03.HomePage()

Root cause:

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: [SQLITE_BUSY] The database file is locked (database is locked)
at itucs.blg361.g03.CategoryEvents.CategoryEventCollection.getCategoryEvents(CategoryEventCollection.java:41)

```
 public List<CategoryEvent> getCategoryEvents() {
    List<CategoryEvent> categoryEvents = new 
            LinkedList<CategoryEvent>();
    try {
        String query = "SELECT id, name, group_id"
                + " FROM event_category";
        Statement statement =  this.db.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (result.next()) {
            int id = result.getInt("id");
            String name = result.getString("name");
            int group_id = result.getInt("group_id");
            categoryEvents.add(new CategoryEvent(id, name, group_id));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(ex.getMessage());
    }
        return categoryEvents;  
}
```

at itucs.blg361.g03.HomePage.(HomePage.java:71)

```
        categories = categoryCollection.getCategoryEvents();
```

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)

Comment: Well, the Exception says it all: the database is locked. This has nothing to do wicket, but relates entirely to your database. Also, I would suggest to use proper Exceptions. UnsupportedOperationException() sematicly wrong here.

Comment: I am using this way:
    catch(Exception e) {  
               e.printStackTrace();

Instead of this one:
catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(ex.getMessage());
    }

Now it seems ok. Any other idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sqlite allows only one writer to the whole database at a time and, unless you selected "WAL" journal mode, no reader while writing. Moreover unless you explicitly ask it to wait, it simply returns the SQLITE_BUSY status for any attempt to access the database while conflicting operation is running.

You can tell sqlite to wait for the database to become available for a specified amount of time. The C-level API is `sqlite3_busy_timeout`; I never used sqlite from Java though, so I don't know where to find it there.

Answer (score 7):

> *(...)* tell sqlite to wait for the database to become available for specified amount of time.

In order to do it from Java, run the following statement just like a simple SQL statement:

```
pragma busy_timeout=30000; -- Busy timeout set to 30000 milliseconds
```