# SQLException: The database file is locked (database is locked)

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, sqlexception

I'm encountering this error

```
java.sql.SQLException:[SQLITE BUSY] The database file  is locked (database is locked)
```

every time I run my jar file that I built. It's fine when I'm running it from my netbeans though. I already tried closing the resultset and preparedstatement but it still shows up when I'm running the jar file. How can I get rid of this? Should I also close the connection?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510409/sqlite-busy-the-database-is-locked-java ,see this one.

Comment: I tried closing the resultset and preparedstatement on the finally block and it still doesn't work

Comment: Do you have multiple connections? , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891006/getting-sqlite-busy-database-file-is-locked-with-select-statements

Comment: My Login.java connects first then my Admin.java connects if the password and username is right on the Login.java.

Comment: and connection you are doing in Login.java has been closed?

Comment: Yes it has been closed in Login.java. It still doesn't work.
EDIT:
It's working now for some reason (I just closed the jar file then opened it again). Thank you.

Comment: well ,the good practice is Connection should to be closed after each query,  there can be more than one process is trying to modify the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing Netbeans first. It's possible it's holding on to the write lock.

Comment: Yes you need to close /release all the resources before giving it to another