# SQLlte [SQLITE_BUSY] The database file is locked (database is locked) error in JAVA Eclipse

Tags: java, database, eclipse, sqlite, maven

pls someone can say what problem is there, why is error, when i make registred and log in database worked. I hope so this part is enough to tell  what the problem is.

By pressed Button information needed to add in my SQlite databe..

```
   @FXML
    public void ActionDelete(Event event)
    {
        System.out.println(User.getText());
        Connection connection = dbregistration.getInstance().getConnection();
        
        
            items=TableView.getItems();
            for(Wallpaper item : items)
            {
                try {
                    String DBUsername = User.getText();
                    String DBEstimateName = EstimateName.getText();
                    
            String DBName =item.getName();
            String DBPrice= item.getPrice().getText();  
            String DBAmount=item.getAmount().getText();
            String DBVien= item.getVien();
            System.out.println(DBUsername+" "+DBEstimateName+ " "+DBName+" "+DBPrice+" "+DBAmount+ " "+ DBVien);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            int status = statement.executeUpdate("insert into DBBASE2 (MaterialName,Price,Quantity,Username,EstimateName,Vien) values('"+DBName+"','"+DBPrice+"','"+DBAmount+"','"+DBUsername+"','"+DBEstimateName+"','"+DBVien+"')");
            if (status>0) {
                System.out.println("user registered");
            }
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();}
        
            }
    
    
    }
```

There is Erorr

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:1012)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:1024)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:989)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._exec_utf8(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._exec(NativeDB.java:94)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.executeUpdate(JDBC3Statement.java:102)
    at Main555.MainPage.ActionDelete(MainPage.java:682)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1729)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8886)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3856)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2584)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

asdasdasdasdsadsadsaddasddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Comment: Can you connect to the database through a direct connection to SQLite and invoke the same `INSERT` statement?  Did you lock the database yourself somehow in a different window/process? Please [edit] your question and add that information, and remove what appears to be stray characters at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the same problem like in this question?
[Getting [SQLITE_BUSY] database file is locked with select statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891006/getting-sqlite-busy-database-file-is-locked-with-select-statements)

Maybe you just need to close the Connection.

```
    Connection connection;
    try {
      Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
      ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(QUERY);
      if (resultSet.next()) { /* do something */ }
    catch (SQLException e) { /* handle exception */ }
    finally {
      if (connection != null) {
      try {
        connection.close(); // <-- This is important
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        /* handle exception */
      }
    }
```