# Java - Database locked

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, csv

I am looking to populate my database with values from a csv file. But it returns SQLITE_BUSY: Database file is locked.

Here is my code

```
try {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("v.csv"));
    String line;

    while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        String[]value = line.split(",");
        System.out.println(value.length);

        String sql = "INSERT into main ([Ticket #], Status, Priority, Department, [Account Name]) "
                + "values ('"+value[0]+"','"+value[1]+"','"+value[2]+"','"+value[3]+"','"+value[4]+"')";

        System.out.println("test");

        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        try {
            pst = DatabaseConnection.ConnectDB().prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.executeUpdate();
        } finally {
            if(pst != null) {
                pst.close();
            }
        }

    }
    br.close();

} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

I'm using different print statements to check where the error is, it seems it can't executeUpdate(); when the loop executes the second time. This is what I get in the console

```
Ticket,Status,Priority,Department,Account Name
5
test
```

Here is my DatabaseConnection just for your reference

```
public class DatabaseConnection {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    public static Connection ConnectDB() {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLITE\_BUSY The database file is locked (database is locked) in wicket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559623/sqlite-busy-the-database-file-is-locked-database-is-locked-in-wicket)

Comment: Sqlite allows only one writer to the whole database at a time and, unless you selected "WAL" journal mode, no reader while writing. Moreover unless you explicitly ask it to wait, it simply returns the SQLITE_BUSY status for any attempt to access the database while conflicting operation is running.

Comment: Yea but it doesn't tell a solution

Comment: Uh, well do you have more than one connection?  If so - don't

Comment: I actually don't. Right now, I've commented all the code that used the connection but the error remains. What could it be? See the discussion below. Its basically unable to excute the execute.Update(); - not even for the first time in the loop

Comment: it is not read-only or something is it.  I recently moved a derby db project to linux and forgot about file permissions - did not work initially.

Comment: OMG! Can't believe this. It was something with the file. What a coincident. I just moved to Windows from Linux yesterday. lol

Comment: No, not a coincidence, experience.  Added a answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are connecting to your database each time you go through the loop.

Create your database connection outside your loop and consume it with in, so it doesnt `getConnection` on each iteration.

```
try
{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("v.csv"));
    String line;

    db = DatabaseConnection.ConnectDB();
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println(line);
        String[]value = line.split(",");
        System.out.println(value.length);

        String sql = "INSERT into main ([Ticket #], Status, Priority, Department, [Account Name]) "
         + "values ('"+value[0]+"','"+value[1]+"','"+value[2]+"','"+value[3]+"','"+value[4]+"')";

        System.out.println("test");

        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        try{   
          pst = db.prepareStatement(sql);
          pst.executeUpdate();
        }finally{
          if(pst != null) {
            pst.close();
          }
        }
    }
    br.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: Just tried what you wrote above. The error remains :(

Comment: @Satnamxv63 what is the value of the `sql` variable on the second iteration?

Comment: it doesn't display. I replaced "test" with sql before PreparedStatement pst = null. And the query is printed only once. So I guess the loop doesn't execute the second time at all.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that your Database it is not read-only or something is it. If you move a db project to linux do not forgot about file permissions.