# Exception: database is locked?

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, jframe

I want to clean data on jTable and database. So i have a Clean Button. I clicked this button when i was run my codes. I am seing Error Message.

I don't understand cause this exception:

**java.sql.SqlException : [SQLITE_BUSY] The Database file is locked(database is locked)**

My codes are :

```
   private void btnCleanActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

    int ndxs[] = jTable1.getSelectedRows();
    if (ndxs.length == 0) {
        show("Error", "You can chose row", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }
    try {

        ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ndxs.length; i++) {
            String id = jTable1.getValueAt(ndxs[i], 0).toString();
            idList.add(id);
        }

        if (idList.size() == 1) {
            db.delPerson(idList.get(0));
        } else {
            String sql =db.toSQL(
                    "delete from passengerInfo where CustomerID in %s", idList.toString().replace("[", "(")
                    .replace("]", ")"));

            //System.out.println(sql);
            db.exec(sql);
        }

        refreshTable();

        show("Result", "Cleaned", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        show("Error", "Didn't clean : \n\n" + e, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

My delPerson codes are :

```
    public void delPerson(String id) throws Exception
{
    String q = String.format("delete from passengerInfo where CustomerID = %s", id);
    conn.createStatement().execute(q);
}
```

Comment: Have you closed the previously open `Connection`/`Statement`s?

Comment: i have DB(database) class and Customer class. Connection and Statement are in DB class.They aren't in Customer Class. btnCleanActionPerformed button is in Customer class. Connection and Statement open in DB. But is it affect my Customer class ?

Comment: Look the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559623/sqlite-busy-the-database-file-is-locked-database-is-locked-in-wicket

Comment: Of course it does, they are connections to the sane database/file